How can i fix C code error C4146 unary minus operator applied to unsigned type.result still unsigned?
Void TestCase() {
struct {

      long long number;

      char expectedBinary[MAX_BINARY_DIGITS], expectedHex[MAX_HEX_DIGITS + 1];

   } testCases[] = {

       {0, "00000000", "00"},

       {-128, "10000000", "80"},

       {255, "11111111", "FF"},

       {INT_MAX, "01111111111111111111111111111111", "7FFFFFFF"},

       {INT_MIN, "10000000000000000000000000000000", "80000000"},

       {2147483649, "", ""}, // Out of range

       {-2147483648-1, "", ""} // Out of range


Even the old -1 trick failed
I used long long for values but it still need to use ll to cast the negative values
